# what's the difference between styling using div and input itself?

Tags: html, css

As seen in the code below, there is class="fields" provided to div when there is already a class="input-fields" in the input element. Why can't we just choose and select one class, aren't they both doing the same thing if to style the input field?

Code:

```css
.fields {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 48%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input-fields {
  height: 20px;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fields">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="input-fields" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same. In this case the div is a parent of the input and some properties on div are passed on to input but properties of input are not passed to div. It only affects input. For example:

```css
/*first case: div has background color and input has not*/
/*all these properties are set for the first div and affects the input (padding and text-align)*/
.firstDiv {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

/*second case: input has background color and div has not*/
/*I'll copy all the properties on firstDiv and use on seconInput to see what happens*/
.secondInput{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstDiv"><input type="text" class="firstInput" placeholder="I am first input"></div>
<div class="secondDiv"><input type="text" class="secondInput" placeholder="I am second input"></div>
```

Both input and div have the same css properties. The first case we gave them to div and second case to input. And now you can see the difference and that they have the same effect, they just do the same thing to different tags with different inheritance.

Comment: how does the properties of div pass to input? Does that mean that div and input each have their own box model, and when we style div, we are actually styling the box model of div?

Comment: Check this out: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

No. The `fields` class is only being used on the div element which means most properties you put in the `fields` tag will only be applied to the div element (though some attributes may be inherited by child elements).

Say you had a `background: black;` property in the fields class. This would **only** make the background of the div black and not the input field.